# ofstream and stringstream doesn't work

Tags: c++, stringstream, ofstream

I have a `std::ofstream os` in my class which I use to log various stuff to a file for example:

```
  `os<< "# Query " << queryCount++ << " -- "
   << "Type: " << typeName << ", "
   << "Instructions: " << instructions << "\n";`
```

In the constructor it is initialized like where `path` represents the path to the file:
`os(path.c_str(), std::ios::trunc)`

I wanted to use a `stringstream` to record all these messages and at the end of a function I just wanted to output that `stringstream` to the file such as:

```
stringstream ss;

ss<< "# Query " << queryCount++ << " -- "
  << "Type: " << typeName << ", "
  << "Instructions: " << instructions << "\n";

os << ss.str();
```

However for some reason although it compiles nothing is printed out. I am not sure what the reason is. I also tried to convert the string to a c string but htat also didn't work. Any ideas about what may be wrong ?

Hope it was clear. Thanks.

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine. Please post a complete example that reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the output mode you are using in the `ofstream` constructor; try:

```
os(path.c_str(), std::ios::out|std::ios::trunc)
```